# Как при нажатии на item остановить фрагмент в android?

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, у меня есть фрагмент:

[image: скрин 1]

Я нажимаю на `play` начинает играть радио, потом я перехожу во вкладку домой и у меня радио не останавливается:

[image: скрин2]

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии домой проиходила остановка?

```
playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mediaPlayer == null){
                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Идет подключение к радиостанции", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(STREAM_URL);
                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
                else if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Идет подключение к радиостанции..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(playPause);
```

Main Activity`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, DrawerLayout.DrawerListener{

```
NavigationView navigationView = null;
Toolbar toolbar = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_priboy) {
        GalleryFragment fragment = new GalleryFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_assa) {
        AsaFragment fragment = new AsaFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

}

@Override
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {


}

@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {

}

@Override
public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {

}
```

}`

Comment: А как Вы воспроизводите радио? Покажите код.

Comment: Поправку сделал, теперь код есть

Answer (score 0):

Обработайте нажатие на кнопку домой. И уже там останавливать воспроизведение.

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Нажата кнопка HOME", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    super.onUserLeaveHint();
}
```

Comment: дело в том что радио у меня играет в Fragment'е а кнопка домой реализовона в navigation drawer, то есть в Main activity

Answer (score 0):

В объект `DrawerLayout` можно установить листенер `DrawerLayout.DrawerListener`

```
DrawerLayout drwLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);
drwLayout.addDrawerListener(new MyListener());
```

Класс `MyListener`:

```
public class MyListener implements DrawerLayout.DrawerListener
{
  @Override
  public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)
  {

  }

  @Override
  public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
  {
    // Здесь остановить плеер
  }

  @Override
  public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView)
  {

  }

  @Override
  public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState)
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: В таком случае радио будет переставать играть в тот момент, когда меню будет открыто.

Comment: это нужно в main activity писать?

Comment: я скинул main Activity, если вам не составит труда могли бы посмотреть?